# Configure dynamic subdomains with wildcard

Tags: subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I want to keep some web projects in my local host so my customers can access some webapps I'm developing.

I've got a domain name that is currently mapped to my dynamic home ip. e.g:

```
demo.mydomain.com -> maps to my currenty ip running apache
```

What I want to to is to map *.demo.mydomain.com to a concrete document path in my home server

```
customer1.demo.mydomain.com -> should point to the folder where the webapp for the customer1 lives
```

I'm aware of apache virtual host configuration (i.e. dynamically map a subdomain to a path in the web server), but the problem is that if I put the previous url in the browser (customer1.demo.mydomain.com) the page is not found, so I guess the dns resolution is failing

The question is how should I configure my domain provider to allow child subdomain wildcards? I'm using Enom (got it after setting up my Google Apps account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a wildcard DNS record. I have no idea how to do that using "Enom", but in Bind it would be a literal wildcard A record, like this:

```
*        A       1.2.3.4
```

This would have to be defined in the demo.mydomain.com sub-domain definition. How exactly you do that depends on what UI Enom provides for you.

Comment: Just to confirm that this works and enom allows wildcards. But I needed to use a CNAME record as I don't have a static IP and I'm using a redirect online service. Just tested with my local Apache and works flawlessly. Thanks!

PS: Enon provides a web that allows editing those records, I accessed it through the Google Apps Admin panel, just in case someone gets here with a similar problem.

Comment: @RickyAH, did you put in Google's IP Address or the googlehosted URL found on other CNAME records in the eNOM online dashboard?